# Strange String comparation

Tags: java, android, string, comparator

I don't know why the comparation of CellType to "Hamster" is false. Wonder why it happened!

[image]

They are exactly the same, even in case sensitive.

Please help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use

```
if (CellType.equals("Hamster")) {
  ...
}
```

The other comparison checks to see if they are the same string Object, not the same string by value.

It is also a good time to lookup the [differences between reference equality and Object equality](http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/data/expressions/22compareobjects.html).

Comment: Thanks for the link :) I understand it now. Wait for 15mins to accept.

Comment: LOL, The Equals Strikes Back!

Comment: @David Yeah, maybe it should be a syntax error instead. I'm a .NET developer, so I didn't know this trick :(

Comment: It's not a syntax error, it's a core tenant of the Java design.  The `==` operator is reserved for comparing whether things are exactly equal.  In other words, it is only used for primitive types and for checking to see if two references refer to the same object.  Due to the ability to create new objects with the same "contents", a second equality operator is needed to have the objects compare themselves via contents.  The `.equals(...)` method will do that, and is polymorphic, allowing objects to override it as necessary.  Java doesn't like operator overloading, so that's it.

Answer (score 0):

`==` is the identity comparison operator (same object). You should use `equals()` when you want to compare equivalence.

Answer (score 0):

Please use

```
 CellType.equals("Hamster");
```

If you want to ignore case then use,

```
 CellType.equalsIgnoreCase("Hamster");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CellType.equals("Hamster")
or
CellType.equalsIgnoreCase("Hamster")
```

Use the above formats, it will be taken care